# Read works, add, edit, delete do not in Grocery Crud library Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, grocery-crud

I have done the example and installed everything.

The read or display method of table works correctly, but whenever I try to add, delete or edit a registry a windows appears and say:

```
404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.
```

Here is my Controller

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('grocery_CRUD_model');
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('grocery_CRUD');
    }


    public function index()
    {
        $crud = new grocery_CRUD();

        $crud->set_theme('datatables');
        $crud->set_table('students');
        $crud->set_relation('class','class','class');
        $crud->display_as('name','Name of Student');
        $crud->set_subject('Students');
        $crud->columns('name','class','roll_no');
        $crud->add_fields('name','class','roll_no');
        $crud->required_fields('name','class','roll_no');
        $crud->unset_export();
        $crud->unset_print();
        $output = $crud->render();
        $this->load->view('home', $output);

    }

}
```

when i click ADD button URL becomes

```
http://localhost/index.php/add
```

**what is missed?
i am new in codeigniter and Grocery Crud...**

Comment: Show me the snapshot of the error page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create another function in `Welcome` controller and move all of the code from `index()` function to new function just like:

```
public function myFunction()
    {
        $crud = new grocery_CRUD();

        $crud->set_theme('datatables');
        $crud->set_table('students');
        $crud->set_relation('class','class','class');
        $crud->display_as('name','Name of Student');
        $crud->set_subject('Students');
        $crud->columns('name','class','roll_no');
        $crud->add_fields('name','class','roll_no');
        $crud->required_fields('name','class','roll_no');
        $crud->unset_export();
        $crud->unset_print();
        $output = $crud->render();
        $this->load->view('home', $output);

    }
```

And redirect your `index()` function to this method:

```
public function index()
    {   
        redirect("welcome/myFunction");
    }
```

Access your grocery crud page at

`http://localhost/index.php/welcome/newFunction`

Or simply

`http://localhost/index.php/welcome`

You're good to go now.